# What are the risks associated with increasing the file size upload limit?

Tags: 2010, file-upload

I have SharePoint 2010 and want to increase the upload file size limit from 50 MB to 100 MB.

Are there any risks or negative effects I can expect from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

going from 50MB to 100MB, i dont see major issue. But couple of things to keep in mind.

- it will increase traffic from User to wfe to SQL. You have to monitor the performance on the servers.
- Plan the database space, as you increasing the file size
- Do the Load testing before hand to check if your farm is ok for the this increase.
- if you have the Antivirus scanning on uploading the Files, may slow down it.
- restore process also headache with big files.
- Here are some issues with upload file [Issues Uploading Large Files To SharePoint](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2012/11/15/issues-uploading-large-files-to-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 2):

Some of the one I can think of is

1. Files are stored in the database and it will grow as you put large files
2. DB size will affect backup and restore strategies
3. You can try using RBS as a workaround

Apart from that I think there won't be any other issues.